# Expandable listview recycling issue

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview, android-recyclerview

Friends, I am using an Expandable listview to display various categories and its subitems. I am using checkbox for selecting the subitems, so that multiple subitems can be selected from various categories. But here I am facing an issue due to the recycling of the views. When I expand the category and tick the checkbox of the subitems in it, then when I click on another category, some checkbox is already checked in it. I assume this is happening due to the recycling of views. I want to solve this issue. I have faced a similar issue with recyclerview also. Please guide me in this. Thank you in advance.
I am pasting my adapter code for reference -

```
 public class DayBookAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<DayBookData> listDataHeader;
    String msubItem,mcategory;
    ArrayList<String>  selecteditems;
    ArrayList<String>  selectedcategories;
    public DayBookAdapter(Context context, List<DayBookData> listDataHeader, ArrayList<String> selectedItems,ArrayList<String> selectedcategories) {
        this._context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.selecteditems = selectedItems;
        this.selectedcategories = selectedcategories;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<DayBookDetailsData> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCh_list();
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final DayBookDetailsData childText = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCh_list().get(childPosition);
        Boolean checkstatus = childText.isIschecked();
        Log.d("checkstatus", "getChildView: "+checkstatus);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.day_book_details_data_item, null);
        }

        TextView item_txt_sub_cat_id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
        item_txt_sub_cat_id.setText(childText.getItem_id());

        CheckBox item_txt_sub_cat_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        item_txt_sub_cat_name.setText(childText.getItem_name());

        item_txt_sub_cat_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;


                msubItem = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCh_list().get(childPosition).getItem_id();
                mcategory = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCategory_id();
                if (cb.isChecked()) {

                    childText.setIschecked(true);
                    selecteditems.add(msubItem);
                    selectedcategories.add(mcategory);
                    Log.d("itemschecked", "items -"+selecteditems+"categories-"+selectedcategories);
                } else {
                    childText.setIschecked(false);
                    selecteditems.remove(msubItem);
                    selectedcategories.remove(mcategory);
                    Log.d("itemschecked", "items -"+selecteditems+"categories-"+selectedcategories);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCh_list().size();
    }

    @Override
    public DayBookData getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DayBookData headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.day_book_data_item, null);
        }
        TextView item_txt_category_id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_id);
        TextView item_txt_category_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        item_txt_category_id.setText(headerTitle.getCategory_id());
        item_txt_category_name.setText(headerTitle.getCategory_name());
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else .
Thank you.

Edited - 
Here is my pojo file for subitems, can anyone tell me what changes is to be done?

```
public class DayBookDetailsData {

    private String item_name;
    private String item_id;

    public boolean isIschecked() {
        return ischecked;
    }

    public void setIschecked(boolean ischecked) {
        this.ischecked = ischecked;
    }

    boolean ischecked;

    public DayBookDetailsData(String item_name, String item_id,boolean ischecked) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.ischecked = ischecked;
    }

    public String getItem_name() {
        return item_name;
    }

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }


}
```

And here is my JSON parsing code,where i am setting the boolean value-

```
  bData.setCategory_id(jObjIn.getString("cat_id"));
                bData.setCategory_name(jObjIn.getString("c_name"));

                JSONArray jArrItemData = new JSONArray(jObjIn.getString("itemdata"));

                for (int j = 0; j < jArrItemData.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jObjItem = new JSONObject(jArrItemData.getString(j));

                    try {

                        String item_id = jObjItem.getString("id");
                        String item_name = jObjItem.getString("item");
                        Boolean checkstatus = false;
                        bData.getCh_list().add(new DayBookDetailsData(item_name, item_id,checkstatus));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                listData.add(bData);
            }

            exp_listview.setAdapter(new DayBookAdapter(getActivity(), listData,selectedItems,selectedcategory));
```

I have updated the file as per your suggestion but it is not helping me .CAn you please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: you have to set if the check box is checked in get child view

Comment: @Cruces have updated the code ,but not helping me anyways ,can you please let me know where do i have to make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each child model object keep an 'isChecked' boolean and update it as you check/uncheck the items. Then explicitly set the checked state of the check box when you get the view.

When recycling views you're safest bet is to assume that every item in the recycled view is in an unwanted state so should be explicitly set.

ex:

```
getChildView(...){

  checkbox.setChecked(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getCheckedStatus());
}

onChildClick(){
getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).setCheckedStatus(...)
}
```

Comment: i have tried what you asked me to do . I have also posted the updated code. But it's not getting it right . Can you please guide me through it.